# How to add Button action in list view in simple cursor adapter

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view which shows certain names fetching from a database using simple cursor adapter like this-

```
wordsDB ob=new wordsDB(this.getActivity(),"DBA",null,1);

 SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getActivity(),R.layout.list_row,c,new String[]{ob.val},new int[]{R.id.textView1},0);
        ListView lv=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now, I want to have buttons like edit and delete in front of each contact i.e in each row. For that I added buttons in my layout file list_row.xml but how do I add Listeners for clicks on those "edit" and "delete" buttons. 
 I tried searching alot but could not find a suitable solution. I tried using custom cursor adapter but ended up confusing as to where should I add my data to the list view i.e. where should I use the above code in newView() or bindView() method.
This is new list_row.xml file with buttons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Kindly guide me .

Comment: 1) extend `SimpleCursorAdapter`, so that it implements `OnClickListener` 2) override `newView` and for every new `View` call `setOnClickListener(this)` 3) override `bindView` and call `view.setTag(cursor.getPosition())` 4) in `onClick` use `v.getTag()` to get the position **NOTE**: no extra memory is allocated since you never call `new OnClickListener()` (you can skip step #2 and setup the listener in `bindView` as well but it requires a little more CPU usage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a custom adapter class extending **SimpleCursorAdapter** and then in bindView() method, you can actually implement button listeners.

Something like this,

```
public class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView != null) {
        return convertView;
    }

    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listform_item);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ibtnDelete);
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

**EDITED**

To make it work with CursorAdapter,

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags){
    super(context,c,flags);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor){
    Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ibtnDelete);
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
});
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent){
    // DO your stuff
}

}
```

Comment: and where do I add the code to put values into the list from the database like the code snippet I mentioned above ..

Comment: That should be in your Activity's onCreate method.

Comment: Ok. And one more thing, if I extend the class with cursor adapter then would it work ?

Comment: yes, you might have to change few constructor parameters but it should work. See my edited lines in answer.

Comment: how do I differentiate between newView and bindView i.e. how do I know what stuff to code in what ?

Comment: check the class specifications and tutorial provided here : https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter

Answer (score 1):

@Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {

```
    selection = ((ChampionActivity) context).getListViewSelection();
    int position = c.getPosition();


    Cursor myCursor = c;

    int nameColumn = myCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_NAME);
    int oneColumn = myCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_ONE);
    int twoColumn = myCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_TWO);


    String firstName = myCursor.getString(nameColumn);

    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.primary_champ_text);

    TextView editTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.editTextView);

    TextView deleteTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.deleteTextView);

    if(textView != null) {
        textView.setText(firstName);
    }

   editTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {

         }
});

   deleteTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {

         }
});
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what stuff should I do inside my bindView and what inside newtView .

Comment: From my understanding, once the adapter is called and constructed the newView and bindView methods are for every row that populates your screen.  With `newView` being called to inflate your `row_layout.xml` layout and `bindView` points to the cursor passed to the adapter and gets the data to assign to view items. Someone please correct me if I am wrong!        Here is the Google documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html and here is a tutorial that helped me: http://www.gustekdev.com/2013/05/custom-cursoradapter-and-why-not-use.html