# ListView with a button simplecursoradapter

Tags: android, listview

I have a tabbed Activity in my app, with 3 tabs. In each tab I have a *listView* populated with a simplecursoradapter. I now added a button to each row of all the *listView*.
Without the button, I can click in the *listView* to go to another page of my app. But now that I added the Button, it's no longer possible. Also, for my button OnClick method, I just added the method in the mainActivity and it works, is that right or should I do it in a different way ?

So : **I want to be able to click in my listView to go to a page and also to click in my button to go to another page, how can  I do that ?**

Here's my list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="16dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_branche_cours"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="English"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" - " />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_designation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Reading"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bAjouterJalon"
    android:layout_width="49dp"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_action_add_jalon"
    android:onClick="Add" />
```

The code of one of my tabs :

```
public class CoursActuel extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_cours_actuel, container, false);

    //récupération de la base de donnees
    final DatabaseHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    //creation d'un adapter et d'un listview
    final CustomAdapter adapter;
    final ListView lvCours;

    //récuperation de la listview à l'aide de son id
    lvCours =(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ListCours);
    //création d'un Cursor qui récupère ce que la requête créée dans le helper aura retournée
    Cursor cursor = dbhelper.getAllCoursActuel();
    //insertion des champs dans la colonne 'nom' dans une tableau
    String[] from = { "b.nom", "c.designation" };
    int[] to = { R.id.text_branche_cours, R.id.text_designation };
    //on crée un adapter qui contiendra le contenu de ce tableau
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.list_row,cursor,from,to);
    lvCours.setAdapter(adapter);
    //on implémente l'adapter à ma listview
    lvCours.setAdapter(adapter);
    //j'avertis que le contenu a été modifié
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

          //ce listener permet de naviguer vers la page de modification de cours
    //en transferant toutes les données en lien avec le cours selectionné
    lvCours.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //je créé un cursor par rapport au cours
            // et j'insère toutes les valeurs en lien avec ce cours
            Cursor cursor_modifier = (Cursor)adapter.getItem(position);
            Intent modifier = new Intent(getActivity(), ModifierCours.class);

            String date_debut= cursor_modifier.getString(1);
            String date_fin = cursor_modifier.getString(2);
            int diziemepoint = cursor_modifier.getInt(3);
            int demipoint =cursor_modifier.getInt(4);
            String description = cursor_modifier.getString(5);
            String designation = cursor_modifier.getString(6);
            int lundi = cursor_modifier.getInt(7);
            int mardi = cursor_modifier.getInt(8);
            int mercredi = cursor_modifier.getInt(9);
            int jeudi = cursor_modifier.getInt(10);
            int vendredi = cursor_modifier.getInt(11);
            int samedi = cursor_modifier.getInt(12);
            String selected_branche = cursor_modifier.getString(13);
            int id_branche = dbhelper.getBrancheID(selected_branche);
            //j'insère toutes les valeurs dans mon Intent, pour les récupérer après
            //a l'aide de la clé
            modifier.putExtra("idold",id_branche);
            modifier.putExtra("branche",selected_branche);
            modifier.putExtra("date_debut",date_debut);
            modifier.putExtra("date_derniercours",date_fin);
            modifier.putExtra("demipoint",demipoint);
            modifier.putExtra("dixiemepoint",diziemepoint);
            modifier.putExtra("description",description);
            modifier.putExtra("designation",designation);
            modifier.putExtra("lundi",lundi);
            modifier.putExtra("mardi",mardi);
            modifier.putExtra("mercredi",mercredi);
            modifier.putExtra("jeudi",jeudi);
            modifier.putExtra("vendredi",vendredi);
            modifier.putExtra("samedi",samedi);
            modifier.putExtra("ajout","listView");
            //je démarre l'activité
            startActivity(modifier);

        }
    });

    return rootView;


}

}
```

And my customAdapterClass

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {



private Context mContext;
private Context appContext;
private int layout;
private Cursor cr;
private final LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.layout = layout;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.cr = c;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return inflater.inflate(layout, null);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);



    Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bAjouterJalon);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, OngletJalonsNotes.class);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: write button.setOnClickListener inside the getView method of ur adapter

Comment: what is the error it is throwing???

Comment: I don't have any error, but if I click in the item of listView nothing happens, do you have an example for the getView() u just told me ?

Comment: post the error stack trace

Comment: there is no getView() method for simple cursor adapter

Comment: make a super call and try once

Comment: @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        // Do something here
        ...
}

Comment: where do I insert that method @roy ?

Comment: Create a custom listView adapter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Button action in list view in simple cursor adapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102219/how-to-add-button-action-in-list-view-in-simple-cursor-adapter)

Comment: try creating a custom list adapter and then u can easily make the click work

Comment: Don't you have an example ? Because it's a bit hard to udnerstand the link u gave me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **remove** your button `OnClick` in `Fragment`, instead add it into `CustomAdapter`.

Create a `CustomAdapter` that extends `SimpleCursorAdapter`

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private Context appContext;
    private int layout;
    private Cursor cr;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.layout = layout;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.cr = c;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return inflater.inflate(layout, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
        final int row_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        ...
        TextView tv_Name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_branche_cours);
        ...
        Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bAjouterJalon);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
              startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In  **CoursActuel** Fragment, change this line

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.list_row, cursor, from, to, 0);
```

to

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.list_row, cursor, from, to, 0);
lvCours.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Refer from [How can I set up button onclicklistner when using simple cursor adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36620324/5156075)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144180/discussion-on-answer-by-john-joe-listview-with-a-button-simplecursoradapter).